# Office 365 business sends file history and files to Cloud automatically?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I just wanted to know that office 365 business premium, sends recently open file history in excel, word or powerpoint or any file I create or open directly to cloud.

Can the admin of the business organisation can see what files being opened and created or saved?

Or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask this question, you should be asking yourself if you should be doing whatever it is you are doing.  If you don't own and manage the machine, application, or service - you should assume someone else can see what you are doing.

Indirectly Office 365 admins can't see what you are working on locally.  However - if you use a company machine, they may have other means of reporting on activity.  Any number of tools for management can report or track activity.

Do note, that if you are saving to the default location - which will usually be OneDrive, then yes, Admins have access to not only the fact that you are working with that document but the document itself.